# Smart Card authentication Windows 11 order

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2022, windows-11

How can I configure so smartcard login is the first choice when logging in?

Our domain is using smart card login for users and LAPS for administration of our workstation which means I cannot enforce only smartcard login.

When I start a user workstation and insert the smart card I wish for windows to select the smartcard so user can enter its PIN instead of having to click "smart card"

Are there any GPO or registry to choice provider order/focus?

We are using only windows server 2022 and windows 11 clients in the domain